# Google App Engine fails when trying to upload static .mp3 files through app.yaml

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, web

I'm trying to make some audio available to my web app that I can access through JavaScript.

The audio file (~20 kB in size) is located in the `root/sounds` folder; like I do with other static files (css stylesheets, JavaScript files, images, etc.), I added this to my app.yaml:

```
- url: /sounds
  static_dir: sounds
```

But then when I try to deploy my app, the tool throws this error:

```
2015-08-02 17:34:35,805 ERROR appcfg.py:2621 An unexpected error occurred. Aborting. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2459, in DoUpload
    self._UploadMissingFiles(missing_files, openfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2600, in _UploadMissingFiles
    self.blob_batcher.Flush()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1464, in Flush
    self.SendBatch()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1423, in SendBatch
    payload,
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 40: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is this a Google App Engine bug, or am I doing something wrong?

I'm on Windows 10, if that makes a difference.

Comment: are you deploying via the launcher or from the command line

Comment: @Anbarasan the launcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** My initial suspicion was off target. The fix, buried in the comments, is to add a `mime_type:` for the audio files to `app.yaml`.

**Update 2:** Tracked it down. `appcfg` uses `mimetypes`, which tries to get an extension to mime type mapping from the local system to associate with a static file. For Windows, this means consulting the registry. A freshly installed Windows 10 doesn't know what an `.mp3` is. The `mime_type:` override in `app.yaml` bypasses the lookup.

That's an interesting stack trace. I have a suspicion that it might to do with one or more of the filenames in `sounds`, but I don't have a Win10 within reach to experiment with.

Do any of the filenames have characters from the extended character set in them? (E.g., diacriticals or something otherwise non-ascii)? If you don't want to show the names, a simple experiment would be to see if you upload a version of the app with a single file in `sounds`, where that file has a generic name (like `example.mp3`). If that works, it's a matter of narrowing down to which name is causing the problem.

*Adding:* It's worth first trying to upload with and empty `sounds` directory, to rule out the case that the problem is elsewhere. Have you already tried that?

Comment: The only sound in the folder is 'success.mp3' so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Can you upload with an empty `sounds`?

Comment: Out now, will give that a try when I'm back in a few hours. Thanks.

Comment: I tried adding a static mp3 to one of my apps (deployed from Linux), and it works fine. Do try an empty sounds folder, if only to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @dave-w-smith I tried to upload the empty folder, and that worked fine. Seems the problem is the mp3 file.

Comment: That's wacky. One more thing to try: Add `mime_type: audio/mpeg` below `static_dir` in `app.yaml`.

Comment: A bit of searching turns up other having this problem when using the launcher (which I never use, so that didn't occur to me). Try using `appcfg.py` from the command line.

Comment: looks like adding the mimetype did it. Thanks!